# Different corner radius of recyclerview items

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, rounded-corners

I'm creating a chat app in Android with Kotlin.

I am using a `recyclerview` and items have one out of 8 backgrounds depending on if they are yours or others' and if they are first/last/middle/alone in time group.

In `recyclerview adapter` there is an usual onBindViewHolder() method with setting those backgrounds.

When the code is like this:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val message = ...
    ...

    textTV.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(
        context,
        when {
            msg.isLastInTimeGroup() && !msg.sentByMe -> R.drawable.chat_message_in_last_bg
            msg.isFirstInTimeGroup() && !msg.sentByMe -> R.drawable.chat_message_in_first_bg
            msg.isMiddleInTimeGroup() && !msg.sentByMe -> R.drawable.chat_message_in_middle_bg
            msg.isLastInTimeGroup() && msg.sentByMe -> R.drawable.chat_message_out_last_bg
            msg.isFirstInTimeGroup() && msg.sentByMe -> R.drawable.chat_message_out_first_bg
            msg.isMiddleInTimeGroup() && msg.sentByMe -> R.drawable.chat_message_out_middle_bg
            else -> if (msg.sentByMe) R.drawable.chat_message_out_bg else R.drawable.chat_message_in_bg
        }
    )
}
```

... it works and looks like first picture below. However, it's inefficient to getDrawable() for every item. So I took drawables out of the function like this:

```
private val inFirstBg: Drawable? = ContextCompat.getDrawable(ctx, R.drawable.chatMessageInFirstBg)
private val inMiddleBg: Drawable? = ContextCompat.getDrawable(ctx, R.drawable.chatMessageInMiddleBg)
private val inLastBg: Drawable? = ContextCompat.getDrawable(ctx, R.drawable.chatMessageInLastBg)
private val inAloneBg: Drawable? = ContextCompat.getDrawable(ctx, R.drawable.chatMessageInBg)
private val outFirstBg: Drawable? = ContextCompat.getDrawable(ctx, R.drawable.chatMessageOutFirstBg)
private val outMiddleBg: Drawable? = ContextCompat.getDrawable(ctx, R.drawable.chatMessageOutMiddleBg)
private val outLastBg: Drawable? = ContextCompat.getDrawable(ctx, R.drawable.chatMessageOutLastBg)
private val outAloneBg: Drawable? = ContextCompat.getDrawable(ctx, R.drawable.chatMessageOutBg)

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val message = ...
    ...

    textTV.background = when {
        msg.isLastInTimeGroup() && !msg.sentByMe -> inLastBg
        msg.isFirstInTimeGroup() && !msg.sentByMe -> inFirstBg
        msg.isMiddleInTimeGroup() && !msg.sentByMe -> inMiddleBg
        msg.isLastInTimeGroup() && msg.sentByMe -> outLastBg
        msg.isFirstInTimeGroup() && msg.sentByMe -> outFirstBg
        msg.isMiddleInTimeGroup() && msg.sentByMe -> outMiddleBg
        else -> if (msg.sentByMe) outAloneBg else inAloneBg
    }
}
```

... and it starts doing drawing problems like in the second picture below.

*Some corners are not rounded at all, text overflows background, etc.*

Background resources look typical (out_middle):

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/blue" />
    <corners android:radius="24dp"
        android:topRightRadius="4dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="4dp"/>
</shape>
```

Why? Where is the problem?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the drawable is adjusted according to the text your first set it to, you should not set the same drawable to every item as your text size is not fixed

It is not inefficient to get background for every resource. I am sure your first method wouldn't lag. To check about inefficiency check the time that piece of code takes to execute, also check the memory by scrolling for atleast 100 items and take a look how it behaves. Let me know if you face any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use multiple itemView types? That way drawable will be loaded once per ViewHolder, and it will be reused appropriately when scrolling. For simplicity you can use your drawable resource ID as `itemViewType`, try this:

```
override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
    val msg = ... // retrieve msg for [position] from dataset
    return when {
        msg.isLastInTimeGroup() && !msg.sentByMe -> R.drawable.chat_message_in_last_bg
        msg.isFirstInTimeGroup() && !msg.sentByMe -> R.drawable.chat_message_in_first_bg
        msg.isMiddleInTimeGroup() && !msg.sentByMe -> R.drawable.chat_message_in_middle_bg
        msg.isLastInTimeGroup() && msg.sentByMe -> R.drawable.chat_message_out_last_bg
        msg.isFirstInTimeGroup() && msg.sentByMe -> R.drawable.chat_message_out_first_bg
        msg.isMiddleInTimeGroup() && msg.sentByMe -> R.drawable.chat_message_out_middle_bg
        else -> if (msg.sentByMe) R.drawable.chat_message_out_bg else R.drawable.chat_message_in_bg
    }
}
```

Then use that value in `onCreateViewHolder`:

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    val holder = ... // your viewholder creation
    holder.textTV.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, viewType)
}
```

And remove your background changing code from `onBindViewHolder` completely.